# Junit test for data types

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am in school and about to learn how to use Junit test.

my question is:

If i have a method and i want to know wether or not this method returns an Integer or not how will do this? is there an Assert that allows me to check the data type of the output?

Hope someone is able to help me

Best regards

Marc Rasmussen

Comment: You can use the instanceof operator like myOutput instanceof Integer

Comment: This isn't such a forum for learning; Tried something new & got a problem then discuss it here, paste some code if possible.. You can use `instanceof` for your purpose. Like `(a instanceof java.lang.integer)` will test if _a is an integer_

Comment: @dshai - I'm not sure I agree. I think it's perfectly reasonable to ask a question prior to coding, provided that question is sufficiently detailed/focused (as I believe this one is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check anything using the:

```
assertTrue(boolean condition)
```

In a case a methode returns an object which you need to check its type you can use something like:

```
asserttrue(o is int);
```

Answer (score 4):

The data type is *statically* declared and asserted by your compiler e.g.

```
public int getValue() { ... }
```

will always return an int. An attempt to do otherwise will force a compialtion error. As such, I wouldn't expect you to use a framework such as JUnit, since this tests the output of the running code.

Conceivable you may return an object which could be an Integer (amongst other things) e.g.

```
public Object getValue() {
   // could be a Long instead...
   return new Integer(3);
}
```

and you *could* check that using `assertTrue()` / `instanceof`. The above is not good programming practise, however! If you're returning a type you should be able to act on it polymorphically without knowing about the specific subclass.